# How to perform a search in array of object flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, search

I am having a Map list with key and values, for example :

```
map<String, dynamic> my_List = [{"name": "mike", "age": "20"}, {"name":"william","age": "23"}].
```

I already tried containsValue but I don't want to use it.

The result i need to get is, when i search for m i need to get [{"name": "mike", "age": "20"}, {"name":"william","age": "23"}] , and when i search 3 i need the result as [{"name":"william","age": "23"}].

Comment: Any specific reason you are using a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` instead of having actual objects? Because I would think it was easier to put this logic inside a `Person` class which can then do the search across relevant fields.

Comment: I agree with @julemand101. Just create a User or Person class with the properties name and age. You could convert your data to List<Person>. Then you can make a search via myList.contains(inputValue) to get all matches. It is also possible to combine it with the .where() method to define whether you are searching through names and or age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `Person` or `User` class as julemand101 has suggested but if You have to work with `Map` try this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> search(String input){
 return my_List.where((e) => e["name"].contains(input) || e["age"].contains(input)).toList();
}
```